# Powershell: Spilt a string to an array of sub-strings such that none when encoded to Uft8 has a byte length > n

Tags: powershell

How can I spilt a string to an array of sub-strings such that no sub-string when encoded to Uft8 with a trailing null, has a byte length > n?

n is always >= 5, so a 4 byte encoded character + null will fit.

The only ways I can think of at the moment, is:

- Split, encode, test the length, and if too big repeat with a smaller split.
- Encode, walk, mask and count the bytes keeping track of boundaries, and split manually

Is there a better way?

The output array could also be an array of utf8 bytes rather than strings if that is easier.

I already know about codepoints, encodings, surrogates and all that. This is specifically about the byte length of the utf8 encoding.

Comment: Since UTF-8 stores variable length data on [high bits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Encoding), going binary tells for sure.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you've tried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok so first off, everything I know about the binary encoding process for UTF-8 I learned just now from the [UTF-8 Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8), so caveat emptor :-). That said, the code below seems to give the correct result for a bunch of test data compared to [@mklement0's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75901000/3156906) (which I have no doubt is correct), so maybe there's some mileage in it...

Happy to hear if there's any howlers in it though - I think it *should* work in principle even if the implementation below is wrong somewhere :-).

In any case, the core function is the one below, which returns the *positions* of the chunks in a utf-8 encoded byte array. I figured once you know the positions you might want to use the bytes in-place (e.g. with `Stream.Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)`, or similar) so I've avoided extracting a copy of the chunks into a new list, but it's pretty easy to use the output to do that if required (see further down).

```
# extracts the *positions* of chunks of bytes in a ut8 byte array
# such that no multi-byte codepoints are split across chunks, and
# all chunks are a maximum of $MaxLen bytes
#
# note - assumes $Utf8Bytes is a *valid* utf8 byte array, so may
# need error handling if you expect invalid data to be passed in.
function Get-UTF8ChunkPositions
{
    param( [byte[]] $Utf8Bytes, [int] $MaxLen )

    # from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8
    #
    # Code point ↔ UTF-8 conversion
    # -----------------------------
    # First code point  Last code point  Byte 1    Byte 2    Byte 3    Byte 4    Code points
    # U+0000            U+007F           0xxxxxxx                                        128
    # U+0080            U+07FF           110xxxxx  10xxxxxx                             1920
    # U+0800            U+FFFF           1110xxxx  10xxxxxx  10xxxxxx                  61440
    # U+10000           U+10FFFF         11110xxx  10xxxxxx  10xxxxxx  10xxxxxx      1048576

    # stores the start position of each chunk
    $startPositions = [System.Collections.Generic.List[int]]::new();

    $i = 0;
    while( $i -lt $Utf8Bytes.Length )
    {

        # remember the start position for the current chunk
        $startPositions.Add($i);

        # jump past the end of the current chunk, optimistically assuming we won't land in
        # the middle of a multi-byte codepoint (but we'll deal with that in a minute)
        $i += $MaxLen;

        # if we've gone past the end of the array then we're done as there's no more
        # chunks after the current one, so there's no more start positions to record
        if( $i -ge $Utf8Bytes.Length )
        {
            break;
        }

        # if we're in the middle of a multi-byte codepoint, backtrack until we're not.
        # we're then at the start of the *next* chunk, and the chunk length is definitely
        # smaller then $MaxLen
        #
        # 0xC0 = [Convert]::ToInt32("11000000", 2);
        # 0x80 = [Convert]::ToInt32("10000000", 2);
        while( ($Utf8Bytes[$i] -band 0xC0) -eq 0x80 )
        {
            $i -= 1;
        }

    }

    # we know all the start positions now, so turn them into ranges.
    # (we'll add a dummy item to help build the last range)
    $startPositions.Add($utf8Bytes.Length);
    for( $i = 1; $i -lt $startPositions.Count; $i++ )
    {
        [PSCustomObject] @{
            "Start"  = $startPositions[$i-1];
            "Length" = $startPositions[$i] - $startPositions[$i-1];
        };
    }

}
```

This function takes advantage of the fact that a *valid* utf8 byte stream is [self-synchronizing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-synchronizing_code), which means in practice that we *don't* have to walk through every single byte in the stream - we can jump anywhere we like and find the start of an encoded codepoint by finding the nearest byte that starts `00xxxxxx`, `01xxxxxx`, or `11xxxxxx` (or equivalently, *doesn't* start `10xxxxxx`), and that's the start of the *next* chunk.

For example, if we jumped `n` bytes from the start of the current chunk and found a byte starting with `10xxxxxx`:

```
      n-2       n-1        n        n+1
... 11110xxx  10xxxxxx  10xxxxxx  10xxxxxx ...
                        ^^^^^^^^
```

then we backtrack to `n-2` as the start of the *next* chunk (so the end of the current chunk is logically one byte before that at `n-3`):

```
      n-2       n-1        n        n+1
... 11110xxx  10xxxxxx  10xxxxxx  10xxxxxx ...
    ^^^^^^^^
```

Example:

```
# set up some test data
$str  = "1234abc€défgabüb";

$utf8 = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($str);
"$utf8"
# 49 50 51 52 97 98 99 226 130 172 100 195 169 102 103 240 159 145 141 97 98 195 188 98

$maxLen = 5 - 1; # exclude NUL terminator
$positions = Get-UTF8ChunkPositions -Utf8Bytes $utf8 -MaxLen $maxLen;
$positions
# Start Length
# ----- ------
#     0      4
#     4      3
#     7      4
#    11      4
#    15      4
#    19      4
#    23      1
```

### Chunks

If you actually want the individual chunked byte arrays with a null terminator you can convert the positions into chunks like this:

```
$chunks = $positions | foreach-object {
    $chunk = new-object byte[] ($_.Length + 1); # allow room for NUL terminator
    [Array]::Copy($utf8, $_.Start, $chunk, 0, $_.Length);
    $chunk[$chunk.Length - 1] = 0; # utf-8 encoded NUL is 0
    @(, $chunk); # send the chunk to the pipeline
};
```

### Strings

Once you've got the individual null-terminated utf-8 encoded chunks, you can revert them back to the null-terminated strings like this if you really want them:

```
$strings = $chunks | foreach-object { [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString($_) }
$strings
```

### Performance

In terms of performance, this seems to scale reasonably well, even if you have to specifically encode the string to a utf8 byte array just to call it. It also performs a whole lot faster with large numbers for `$MaxLen` as it gets to jump longer distances for each chunk...

A rough test on my machine:

```
$sample = "1234abc€défgabüb" * 1000000;
$sample / 1mb;
# 17

Measure-Command {
    $utf8 = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($sample);
    $maxlen = 1024;
    $positions = Get-UTF8ChunkPositions $utf8 $maxlen;
    $chunks = $positions | foreach-object {
        $chunk = [byte[]]::new($_.Length + 1); # allow room for NUL terminator
        [Array]::Copy($utf8, $_.Start, $chunk, 0, $_.Length);
        $chunk[$chunk.Length - 1] = 0; # utf-8 encoded NUL is 0
        @(, $chunk); # send the chunk to the pipeline
    };
};

# TotalMilliseconds : 7986.131
```

Although if performance is your main concern then maybe PowerShell isn't the right choice for you :-)...

Comment: Nicely done. Performance will depend on the characters that make up the input string: it will be best with all-ASCII-range characters, and worst with all-non-BMP characters.

Comment: @mklement0 - True. I found the biggest performance determinant though was the size of the chunks - the function has to loop roughly ```byte array length / chunk length``` times, so if chunk length is large if barely has to do anything :-).

Comment: I suppose another way to do it is to simply jump by (n-1)/4 characters at a time

Comment: Tried jumping by (n-1)/4 characters at a time: `'' -split "(.{7})" -ne '' | ForEach {$_}`, but `-split` happily splits surrogate pairs though :( Is there a way to split on boundaries, or we still have to manually adjust?

Comment: @Adamarla - I think the nearest you’re going to get for that is @mklement0’s answer - anything native will have to do pretty much the same thing internally anyway. The problem is your constraints are defined in two namespaces - i.e don’t split encoded Unicode *codepoints*, and don’t exceed a maximum encoded *code unit* length. Dotnet strings are natively UTF-16 encoded, so one *or* two (for surrogate pairs) code units per codepoint, and UTF-8 is 1-4 code units per codepoint which means you can’t just do basic math on string or byte stream lengths - you have to *parse* the data *somehow*…

Answer (score 4):

Note:

- This answer creates a list of (.NET) *substrings* of the input string, by partitioning the input string into substrings whose *[UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) byte representation* doesn't exceed a given *byte* count.
- To create a list of these UTF-8 byte representations instead, i.e. *byte arrays*, see [mclayton's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75909031/45375).

---

The following:

- iterates over the input string character by character or [surrogate pair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Character_Set_characters#Surrogates) by surrogate pair

  - Note that .NET [`[char]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Char) instances, which .NET [`[string]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.String) instances are composed of, are unsigned 16-bit Unicode *code units*, which can therefore only *directly* encode Unicode glyphs with code points up to `U+FFFF` (glyphs in the so-called BMP (Basic Multilingual Plane), and require a (surrogate) *pair* of code units to encode Unicode characters outside that plane, i.e. those with code points *greater than* `U+FFFF`, a range of characters that notably includes *emoji*, such as .
- extracts substrings based on their UTF-8 byte-sequence length, inferred from each single character's Unicode code point / whether a character and the subsequent one form a surrogate pair (which implies a code point greater than `U+FFFF`, which in turn implies `4` bytes), based on [this Wikipedia table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Encoding).
  <sup>Tip of the hat to [mclayton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3156906/mclayton) for pointing out that keeping track of *indices* in the original string combined with `.Substring()` calls is sufficient to extract chunks - no need for a [string builder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Text.StringBuilder).</sup>
- uses a [`` System.Collections.Generic.List`1 ``](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.Generic.List-1) instance to collect all chunks in a list.

```bash
# Sample string
$str = '1234abc€défg'

$maxChunkLen = 4 # the max. *byte* count, excluding the trailing NUL

$chunks = [System.Collections.Generic.List[string]]::new()
$chunkByteCount = 0
$chunkStartNdx = 0
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $str.Length; ++$i) {
  $codePoint = [int] $str[$i]
  $isSurrogatePair = [char]::IsSurrogatePair($str, $i)
  # Note: A surrogate pair encoded as UTF-8 is a *single* non-BMP
  #       character encoded in 4 bytes, not 2 3-byte *surrogates*.
  $thisByteCount = 
    if ($isSurrogatePair) { 4 } 
    elseif ($codePoint -ge 0x800) { 3 } 
    elseif ($codePoint -ge 0x80) { 2 } 
    else { 1 }
  if ($chunkByteCount + $thisbyteCount -gt $maxChunkLen) {
    # Including this char. / surrogate pair would make the chunk too long.
    # Add the current chunk plus a trailing NUL to the list...
    $chunks.Add($str.Substring($chunkStartNdx, ($i - $chunkStartNdx)) + "`0")
    # ... and start a new chunk with this char. / surrogate pair.
    $chunkStartNdx = $i
    $chunkByteCount = $thisByteCount
  }
  else {
    # Still fits into the current chunk.
    $chunkByteCount += $thisByteCount
  }
  if ($isSurrogatePair) { ++$i }
}
# Add a final chunk to the list, if present.
if ($chunkStartNdx -lt $str.Length) { $chunks.Add($str.Substring($chunkStartNdx) + "`0") }

# Output the resulting chunks
$chunks
```

Output (annotated):

```bash
1234 # 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 bytes (+ NUL)
abc  # 1 + 1 + 1 bytes (+ NUL)
€d   # 3 + 1 bytes (+ NUL)
éfg  # 2 + 1 + 1 bytes (+ NUL)
   # 4 bytes (+ NUL)
```

Note that all chunks except the first one have *fewer* than 4 characters (the byte-count limit, excluding the NUL), due to containing multi-byte-as-UTF-8 characters and/or due to the *next* character being such a character and therefore not fitting into the current chunk.